# Resize Opera browser in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: resize, opera

I can't resize the Opera browser window! Using the mouse the grip handles are too small, so I always miss them. Also, `alt+space` does not bring up a menu as it normally does. According to a message in 
[forums.opera.com](https://forums.opera.com) the solution should be to disable "Instant Search" which is bound to alt+space. Unfortunately that doesn't work either, so I'm stuck. This is unfortunate, since in all other respects I find Opera is the best choice. (Acer laptop, Ubuntu 19.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow indeed out-of-the-box Opera borders are utterly ellusive. (also Opera seems to ignore system theme, which doesn't help the issue. you should bring it up as a bug with them : https://help.opera.com/en/computer-bug-wizard/)

there is a quick fix for this though, which is using the keyboard shortcuts for this :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to start resizing, then use the arrow keys to resize the window. Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> will save your resize, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will revert the resize back.

the menu is brought up with <kbd>Alt</kbd>

this on the other hand makes sense to me. it's a Linux standardisation issue.

Comment: That was new to me. I never used Alt+F8 before, but it seems to work with all windows in fact. Learning all the time, lovely!

Comment: yeah same here. been having fun with it. while I have you this one is as old as the world itself and works on any os other than mac : Win+Arrow Keys

Comment: @BerntRibbum did this solve your issue? you should mark this answer as the answer if so.

Comment: No problem - done. However, the real solution was to use Firefox instead...